# Cannot change redux state with a action in a component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Action on button does not perform the action to change the sorting object which sort all itens in a list (another component). I expect the button to perform this changes passing the sortBy variable on this.props.dispatch(orderBy(sortBy)) or another dynamic way without a button.

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import orderBy from '../actions/sorting';

const TYPES = [
    { slug: "title", description: "Title" },
    { slug: "author", description: "Author" },
    { slug: "editionYear", description: "Edition Year" }
  ];

  class BookListSorter extends React.Component {
    state = {
        sortBy: [{ title: "asc" }]
      };

      // Helper methods
      getSortByKeyForIndex = index =>
        Object.keys(this.state.sortBy[index] || {})[0];
      getSortByValueForIndex = index =>
        Object.values(this.state.sortBy[index] || {})[0];

      changeSort = (key, index) => e => {
        // This is what is called when an select option changes
        const { target } = e; // Save target from event to use in the callback
        this.setState(({ sortBy }) => {
          // Use a function for atomicness - this prevents state from being out of sync

          // Get the type from the event object if the onchange handler is for the type,
          //  otherwise get from sortBy object
          const type =
            key === "type" ? target.value : this.getSortByKeyForIndex(index);
          // Get the direction from the event object if the onchange handler is for the direction,
          //  otherwise get from sortBy object
          const direction =
            key === "direction" ? target.value : this.getSortByValueForIndex(index);
          // If both options are set, replace the indexed spot in the sortby object
          // Return updated state.
          return type || direction
            ? sortBy.splice(index, 1, { [type]: direction })
            : sortBy.splice(index, 1);
        });
      };

      filterTypes = index => ({ slug }) => {
        // Filter out already used keys from previous rows
        const sortByKeys = this.state.sortBy
          .slice(0, index)
          .reduce((keys, sortObj) => keys.concat(Object.keys(sortObj)[0]), []);
        return !sortByKeys.includes(slug);
      };

      render() {
        const { sortBy } = this.state;

        const lastIndex = sortBy.length - 1;
        // Only add a new row if the one above it is completely filled out
        const shouldAddNewRow =
          this.getSortByKeyForIndex(lastIndex) &&
          this.getSortByValueForIndex(lastIndex);
        const rowCount = shouldAddNewRow ? sortBy.length + 1 : sortBy.length;

        return (
          <div>
            <h1>Choose sort order</h1>
            {Array.from(Array(Math.min(rowCount, TYPES.length))).map(
              (dummy, index) => (
                <div>
                  <span>Row {index}: </span>
                  <select
                    defaultValue={this.getSortByKeyForIndex(index)}
                    onChange={this.changeSort("type", index)}
                  >
                    <option value="">None</option>
                    {TYPES.filter(this.filterTypes(index)).map(
                      ({ slug, description }) => (
                        <option value={slug}>{description}</option>
                      )
                    )}
                  </select>
                  <select
                    defaultValue={this.getSortByValueForIndex(index)}
                    onChange={this.changeSort("direction", index)}
                  >
                    <option value="">None</option>
                    <option value="asc">Ascending</option>
                    <option value="desc">Descending</option>
                  </select>
                  <br />
                </div>
              )
            )}
            <br />
            <button onClick={() => this.props.dispatch(orderBy(sortBy))}>sort</button>
          </div>
        );
      }
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        sorting: state.sorting
    };
};

//ACTIONS

//ADD BOOK

const addBook = ({ title = '', author = '', editionYear = 0} = {}) => ({
    type: 'ADD_BOOK',
    book: {
        title,
        author,
        editionYear
    }
});

//SORT BY

const orderBy = (order) => ({
    type: 'SORT_BY',
    orderBy: order
});

//book reducer

const bookReducerDefaultState = [];
const bookReducer = (state = bookReducerDefaultState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'ADD_BOOK': 
            return [
                ...state,
                action.book
            ];
        default:    
            return state;
    };
};

//sorting reducer

const sortingReducerDefaultState = { 
   orderBy: [{title: 'asc'},{author: 'asc'}]
};
const sortingReducer = (state = sortingReducerDefaultState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'SORT_BY':
            return {
                ...state,
                orderBy: action.orderBy
            };
        default: 
            return state;
    };   
}

function compareBy(a, b, orderBy) {
    const key = Object.keys(orderBy)[0],
      o = orderBy[key],
      valueA = a[key],
      valueB = b[key];
    if (!(valueA || valueB)) {
      console.error("the objects from the data passed does not have the key '" + key + "' passed on sort!");
      return 0;
    }
    if (+valueA === +valueA) {
      return o.toLowerCase() === 'desc' ? valueB - valueA : valueA - valueB;
    } else {
      if (valueA.localeCompare(valueB) > 0) {
        return o.toLowerCase() === 'desc' ? -1 : 1;
      } else if (valueA.localeCompare(valueB) < 0) {
        return o.toLowerCase() === 'desc' ? 1 : -1;
      }
    }
    return 0
  }

  function getSortedBooks(books, orderBy) {
    orderBy = Array.isArray(orderBy) ? orderBy : [orderBy];
    return books.sort((a, b) => {
      let result
      for (let i = 0; i < orderBy.length; i++) {
        result = compareBy(a, b, orderBy[i])
        if (result !== 0) {
          return result
        }

      }
      return result
    })
  }


//store creation 

const store = createStore(
    combineReducers({
        books: bookReducer,
        sorting: sortingReducer
    })
);

store.subscribe(() => {
    const state = store.getState();    
    const sortedBooks = getSortedBooks(state.books, state.sorting.orderBy) 
    console.log(sortedBooks);
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(BookListSorter);
```

Can anyone help with this issue. Since the button i set up is not working?

Comment: There is a lot to unpack with this. How do you know it's not working? Does is update the state? What does your `orderBy` action look like, and what does the reducer look like? It looks like it _should_ work as is, but there is a lot we can't see here.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with how you wired up your Redux, but I am still unsure how to know it's not working. Does the redux state get updated when the `sort` button is clicked? Is the information not sorting, or does the state not update?

Comment: Hi Matty. I have installed the redux devtool and notice something. When I click the button, the sort reducer is updated, but not the book reducer. Then when I click one more time, it works. But the sorted book array is not rendered to the screen.

Comment: if you wanna take a look, that's my project repository https://github.com/adrianosotos/bookshelf

Answer (score 0):

**Note: This was an answer to the original question**

---

The best way to get the value of a `select` element in React is to add an `onChange`handler.

In your example, it might look something like this:

```
<select onChange={(event) => this.setState({ firstType: event.target.value })}>
  <option value="title">Title</option>
  <option value="author">Author</option>
  <option value="editionYear">Edition Year</option>
</select>
<select onChange={(event) => this.setState({ firstDirection: event.target.value })}>
  <option value="asc">Ascending</option>
  <option value="desc">Descending</option>
</select>
```

By changing the above select inputs, the state would look like this:

```
{
  firstType: 'author',
  firstDirection: 'desc'
}
```

(The state wont automatically be set until changes are made, so you would have to initialize separately.)

You would then need to transform that object into the shape you need.

This is just an example, I'll leave it up to you to transform the state into the shape that you need and to connect up redux since it looks like that's what you intend to do with the import of `connect`.

Note: if the `option` tags don't have a `value` attribute set, the value in `event.target.value` would be the content inside the tags.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I followed what you've said. I created an event for each of the select tags and also an setState. But i'm having trouble to transform it to an object and pass it as an argument in a function. Is it possible to transform it in an object? 
For exemple: 
state = {
firstType: 'title', firstDirection: 'asc', secondType: 'author', secondDirection: 'desc'
} 
transform to {title: 'asc'} and {author: 'desc'} 
to be an argument in the function:
store.dispatch(sortBy([{title: 'asc'}, {author: 'desc'}]);

Comment: Basically, once you have the state object, transforming it might look like this:

`const sortBy = [{ [firstType]:firstDirection }, { [secondType]:secondDirection }, { [thirdType]:thirdDirection }];`

I would make a block to conditionally `push` the objects into the `sortBy` array IF the `type` and `direction` are present.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not having success in sorting my itens :(
i've setup the following: 
`state = {
        firstType: '',
        firstDirection: '',
        secondType: '',
        secondDirection: '',
        thirdType: '',
        thirdDirection: ''
    };
    sortingBy = [
        {[this.state.firstType]:this.state.firstDirection }, { [this.state.secondType]:this.state.secondDirection }, { [this.state.thirdType]:this.state.thirdDirection }
    ];`
` <button onClick={() => {
                    this.props.dispatch(sortBy(this.sortingBy))}}>Sort
                    </button>`

Comment: the `<button onClick={() => {
                    this.props.dispatch(sortBy(this.sortingBy))}}>Sort
                    </button>` is where i`m triggering the action... but it's not working. It only last this to finish the logic on my app :'''(

i`m using pluggin "transform-class-properties" on babel

Comment: Check out this really robust example that I cooked up:
https://codesandbox.io/s/w2xvw3nrx5

It sets the state with what I believe to be a valid `sortBy` array.based on your original question.

I will be updating with comments.

Comment: To bypass the terrible commenting syntax, please add edits to your original post with the new context and update question(s) :)

Comment: Yes, sorry. I was editing when you send me the code on condesandbox. Thanks for the help man! The only issue which I'm not understanding is the empty tags between the selects. When I pass it to my editor, it shows an error and doensnt compile to browser. I've tried to change it to a div, but throws an error I'm a newby yet to programming and i haven't seen this before. I'm updating my code above.

Comment: The empty tags are React’s fragments available in version 16.2.0 and above. The <> is just sugar syntax and probably requires a specisl babel config. I’m surprised that divs dont work, but try <React.Fragment>

Comment: It worked to pass your code! I had success in changing the `<>` to `<div>`. I think I was doing some typo. I've updated my code and instead of rendering the variable sortBy, as your code, i'm trying to perform an action to change a sorting object (connected to redux) which will perform the sorting of a list of books. But nothing happens when I click. I've tried many different options, but none of them work :(